# Lock calendar view to a certain part of the day

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to get Google Calendar to show only the relevant part of the day? I don't want to scroll up and down. Is there a way to lock the view to, for example, 7am to 9pm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the "[Hide morning and night](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/hide-morning-and-night-hours-in.html)" Lab is no longer around in the "new" Google Calendar.

> How often do you have something scheduled at 3am? What about 10pm? If the answer is almost never, you might want to try out the Hide morning and night lab in Google Calendar.
>
> With a simple drag of a slider you can fold all those empty hours into a single row to set the time range you want to hide. The folded rows still show all your events, just in more compact form.

However, [Raphael Schaad](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/197505/raphael-schaad) [points out](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121368/197505) that the [Hide morning in calendar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-morning-in-calendar/oaikandahkibeihnampagmegnpfefhca) Chrome extension restores most of this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK no, there isn't a way to lock the view on a set time interval. Have you tried viewing in agenda mode? Typically that will condense your schedule into a tighter frame than day view will allow.

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome (and on other browsers, I assume) the entire day's schedule (ie, any all-day events plus 0:00-23:59) appears if I shrink the web page enough, using 
COMMAND and "-" on the Mac or CTRL and "-" on the PC. I can now see anything at a glance (especially to see if the day is free and to not miss any entries at odd hours).  Note that, at this point, the font is tiny, so I might have to select an entry to read the details.
   Not ideal, but it works when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that works is to zoom out to around 80%. This will let you see everything but in small fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to 24 hour time layout.  Reload.  Switch back.  Reload.

Answer (score 0):

In the app, at the top, go to
Calendar
Preferences tab
Show: (I selected 24 hours at a time to see the whole day)