# How can I change Google calendar to view all 24 hours for each day in the week view mode, without having to scroll?

Tags: google-calendar

Problem: When I go to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r, I don't see all 24 hours for each day. Instead, I only see between 5 AM and 6 PM (I greyed out all my events for privacy):

[image]

Question: How can I change Google calendar to view all 24 hours for each day in the week view mode, without having to scroll? I don't want to zoom out because then the font is too small to read.

Note: My monitor has an aspect ratio of 16:9 or something close to it, which is typical for computers. The issue occurs on monitors that  have an aspect ratio of 16:9 or something close to it. If one's monitor/screen an aspect ratio of 9:16 or something close to it, then the issue isn't present. Example from [Blind Spots](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/197518/blind-spots): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebzm5.jpg

---

I am aware of the question [Google Calendar view whole day at once](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/41041/18147) but the OP actually wants a way to lock the view to 7am to 9pm, whereas I want to see all 24 hours.

As of 2023-07-21, the problem is [still present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySl1C.png).

Comment: The question doesn't include enough details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Franck. It's better, but you "can't keep the cake and eat it too". It looks this should be sent directly to Google or you should post this on a "job board" like codementor.io with your solution requirements i.e. userscript, web browser extension, budget., etc.

Comment: This question isn't a practical question about using a Web Application.  Any web page whose content didn't fit in the viewable area would require zooming or scrolling.  Zooming makes it smaller but you don't like it smaller.  What kind of solution are you seeking?

Comment: FYI the 16:9 aspect ratio of your current display is not an issue.  Your display simply doesn't have the vertical resolution to display 24 hrs at 100% zoom.  You can **[1]**  increase the vertical resolution by rotating the display or replacing it,  or **[2]** decrease the zoom until it fits.   My display is also 16:9: [1:1 screenshot (right half of display)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3937.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to configure Google Calendar so that one may view all 24 hours for each day in the week view mode, without having to scroll. There is no built-in feature implementing that functionality. Google Calendar only allows to change how many days to display. The only options that don't require additional code are zooming out or having some monitor with a portrait ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. On the Calendar page where it asks you Day, Week, Month, etc. Select Schedule. There you go!!!